# What controls the destination of EVT_MOUSEWHEEL events?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am building a visualisation tool with a custom timeline view, and I'm trying to understand what controls who receives `EVT_MOUSEWHEEL` events.

I have 3 panes in my app: an empty `wxPanel`, a `wxScrolledWindow` containing some textctrls and other bits, and my custom timeline (derived directly from `wxWindow`).

The custom timeline handles `EVT_MOUSEWHEEL` events to zoom in and out. This only works once I've clicked on the timeline view, and once I've done that it always works regardless of mouse position.

The `wxScrolledWindow` seems to ignore any use of the scroll regardless of mouse position or previously 'selected' widgets.

What actually controls the receiver of mousewheel events? Is there some concept of 'focus' that I'm not aware of. The behaviour I actually want is for the widget underneath the mouse to receive the event - how do I achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the OS version.  Assuming Windows, yes, focus matters.  The message is sent to the child window that has the focus.  But changed in Win10, the new "Scroll inactive windows when I hover over them" system option is turned on by default.  Makes it more compatible with the kind of commonly used program that doesn't use child controls, like a browser or an Office program.

Comment: Yes I'm on Windows. I'm aware of that setting, but I thought that related to 'frames' (i.e. applications) rather than individual widgets. I'm talking about individual widgets in an app.

Comment: @WillW, did you bind any mouse events to anything?

Comment: In the timeline widget, yes (static event table). But it only receives the events if I click on the widget first.

Comment: The comment by @HansPassant should be the answer, wxWidgets provides native behaviour for your program, including following the platform convention for mouse scrolling.